# Intellij Idea does not detect and underline non-existing methods in the editor pane

Tags: intellij-idea

In the idea editor and my java project , idea does not detect non-existing methods and underline in the editor pane, so i could not use alt + enter to generate new methods.

Example screenshot is below :

[image: screenshot from idea]

BTW : powersave mode is disabled, in the project setting sources are selected.

Project window is seen below:

[image: project view]

I created demo maven project in idea, still the problem continues.

I created DemoNew Class.

```
public class DemoNew {

}
```

Then i created DemoImpl class:

```
public class DemoImpl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DemoNew demoObject = new DemoNew();

        demoObject.ssss(); // idea does not detect this non-existing method.

    }
}
```

As seen above, idea does not detect the non existing ssss method in DemoNew class.

I uploaded demo project and my settings in intellij idea.

[demo project and settings](https://files.fm/u/y7rjxr96#_)

After compiling project, still idea does not underline non-existing method with red color in the editor pane.

[image: after compiling project]

Comment: Can you show the Project window as well? Sometimes IntelliJ goes wonky when using the scene builder for me

Comment: i use embedded scene builder of intellij

Comment: @engtuncay do you have File | Power Save mode enabled?

Comment: powersave mode is disabled. is it related to inspection configurations ?

Comment: @engtuncay Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart. Share [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if the issue persists.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, i tried invalidate caches and restart , but the problem continues. thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @engtuncay please zip and share the project directory.

Comment: @CrazyCoder i uploaded demo project and exported my settings of idea. https://files.fm/u/y7rjxr96#_

Comment: @engtuncay can't reproduce: https://i.imgur.com/3EL9hSm.png. Try to delete [IDE folders](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) to start from scratch.

Comment: @CrazyCoder it seems you did right. When you compile the project , it gives errors , but without compiling project , idea could not detect non-exising method.

Comment: @engtuncay I didn't compile the project, the error on screenshot was detected on the fly.

Comment: @CrazyCoder the problem is not compiling project, because i called a non-existing method in DemoNew class, so idea editor should warn me that method does not exist in that class and underline it with red color, but it does not warn me and underline the method. i saw your picture , your idea warn you , but mine does not.

Comment: @engtuncay did you try the clean IntelliJ IDEA installation with the default settings as I've suggested in the comment already? Does it help?

Comment: @CrazyCoder yes, i uninstalled intellij idea and deleted app data and created a new project, but still the problem continues. thanks. i think i should accustome to this situation.

Comment: @engtuncay please [submit a ticket to support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) with the [logs folder zipped](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains Team answered the question

> Looks like JDK uses wrong locale:
>   https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-190718 Please try to add
>   "-Dsun.locale.formatasdefault=true" option to JVM settings.

I added that parameters from intellij idea / help / edit custom vm options.

[image: edit-custom-vm-menu]

And parameters are seen below.

```
-Dsun.locale.formatasdefault=true
-Duser.language=en
-Duser.region=US
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

[image: parameters in custom vm options]

I added last four items in the file.

That fixed the problem.